# Complete Debates?

Tags: denomination-survey

Where could one find complete debates of issues within Christianity (that which separates, creates denominations) or related to Christianity (existence of a Creator)? It would have every argument for or against the issue and replies to the arguments from both/all sides.

Currently, I assume we have to find all books about the issue and map it out ourselves. Wikipedia would be another option, but I'm not sure how up to date it is because of its NPOV and no original research rules.

I have no specific issue in mind, so this will probably be closed. I'm looking for any places with a complete debate about any issue and that is updated regularly.

Comment: This is a good question; it's just not a good question _for this site_, as it is a list question. Good Q&A questions should be answerable by a single, correct answer. Not lists of correct answers.

Comment: Which site is this question good for?

Comment: I don't know... perhaps a discussion forum somewhere?  Or google?

Comment: What would you change to make this question good for this site?

Comment: Ask a specific question that could have a single, correct answer. "Where can I find a recorded copy of XYZ debate?" would be an example (although that may not be a good fit for this site's SCOPE, as it's not really about Christian doctrine).

Answer (score 2):

Such a work would be too large for any one resource.

You may want to look at:

- Theopedia (a Wikipedia like reference)
- The Cathechism of the Catholic Church, the Catholic Encyclopedia, and canon law (all of which do a good job of pointing out controversies, says the Protestant)
- the Ante and Post-Nicene Fathers by Phillip Schaff. (the Patristics were often writing against heresies of one form or another)
- In general, a good systematic theology book (JI Packer has a good concise tome) will also point out the things that a Christian "should" believe.

I've found it's a lot easier to concentrate on knowing my bible well, know enough about Trinitarian orthodoxy and good Christology, and then just apply it to what I am bring presented with. Heresies are like and endless supply of orcs. There are always enough and battling each one tires you out too much to concentrate on the big bad. Instead, simply "be prepared to give an answer for your faith at all times," and "insofar as possible, live peaceably with all men. ". "Do not concern yourself with genealogies and disputations," but rather "put on the full armor of Christ that you can withstand the evil one. "